# get webpages from command line

Tags: internet, command-line

How can I get the contents of a webpage from the command line? On my mac I use the `curl` command, but there is no such command for the android command line. what command do I use?

Answer (score 3):

There is a port for cURL for Android:

- http://thesoftwarerogue.blogspot.com/2010/05/porting-of-libcurl-to-android-os-using.html

But I think that your best bet for this one is the git repo:

- https://github.com/jahrome/curl-android

  > ```
  >                              _   _ ____  _
  >                       ___| | | |  _ \| |
  >                      / __| | | | |_) | |
  >                     | (__| |_| |  _ <| |___
  >                      \___|\___/|_| \_\_____|
  > ```
  >
  > README
  >   Curl is a command line tool for transferring data specified with URL
  >   syntax. Find out how to use curl by reading the curl.1 man page or the
  >   MANUAL document. Find out how to install Curl by reading the INSTALL
  >   document.
  >   libcurl is the library curl is using to do its job. It is readily
  >   available to be used by your software. Read the libcurl.3 man page to
  >   learn how!

Comment: I found this distribution of curl that is more easy to install http://curl.haxx.se/download.html It works just fine.